# What is the first use of the word "Padawan"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

I was thinking about the phrase 'young padawan,' and it seemed to me to be a permanent part of Star Wars lore. Yet, I definitely remember being into Star Wars well before the prequels, while I just re-watched the original trilogy and don't remember hearing the term padawan anywhere. There are multiple uses of the word 'apprentice;' but in movie terms, padawan seems to be fist introduced in Episode I.

In the greater Star Wars universe and all its associated products, what is the first use of the word 'padawan'? To be clear, I don't care about what is canon and what is not, I want to know the first time it showed up in any written script, book, video game, etc.

Comment: Some time around the Prequel Trilogy

Comment: @Edlothiad I remember it from before then, as CBredlow's answer tells us. I don't know if I came across it in a video game, RPG, card game or novel, but I knew it before the prequels.

Comment: It might help to clarify whether you're looking for the "first" usage in-world, or out-of-world. Thankfully @CBredlow seems to answer both ("Phantom Menace" for in-world, and the 1974 script is the first time *Lucas* used it, which would've be around the time of "A New Hope" in-world)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the current canon, the first time the word 'padawan' shows up is in Phantom Menace, where Qui-Gon calls Obi-Wan that.

According [this rough draft by Lucas in 1974](http://maddogmovies.com/almost/scripts/starwars_rough5-74.pdf) (page 18) we see the first ever reference to the word 'Padawan' as a student to the Jedi.(Thanks NKCampbell for finding it)

This is the first time we see the word written down, and much of the expanded universe used this as a reference, as they had to get approval from Lucasfilm for their works.

The word also appears in the 1993 series *Tales of the Jedi* as well as the series *Knights of the Old Republic* (the comics of course, since they came before the games). However, some of the earlier issues of *Tales of the Jedi* used the phrase "jedi apprentice" and later did padawan.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I clarified that I want to know the first time it appeared in _any_ format. If it was in an early draft for the original Star Wars, can you find a reference to that?

Comment: @kingledion trying to track down the source other than "George said it according to Wookiepedia"

Comment: http://maddogmovies.com/almost/scripts/starwars_rough5-74.pdf - page 18 - no idea how valid this doc is - has a lot of things I do know were in the original draft (Utupau, Jedi Bendu, etc...)

Comment: @NKCampbell thanks, I knew the word had appeared in the Dark horse comics adaptation of the rough draft.

Comment: I'm quite positive that the word appeared somewhere else before TPM came out, I just can't place where. A trading card with some trivia on it? One of the guide books or RPG books? I feel like I knew the word Padawan before I ever saw the movie. But maybe not.

Comment: @CreationEdge you’re right it’s been out there, and the ‘appearance’ section of the wookiepedia page places a lot of things that it was mentioned in. However, he asked the first appearance in any media, and I think 3 years before the first movie might win that race

Comment: Oh, I wasn't criticizing the first draft or anything. Although, I thought _Jedi Academy_ came out in like 2013, quite a long time after TPM.

Comment: @CreationEdge The one where we first see Luke's academy on Yavin IV and Exar Kun shows up to cause trouble, that was a long time ago (maybe I got the trilogy name wrong)

Comment: Yeah but when was that draft made available to the public?

Answer (score 11):

You're right, the term was introduced in *The Phantom Menace*. [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padawan/Legends) states:

> The term Padawan first appeared as far back as George Lucas's first
>   story treatments for Star Wars. However, it was not heard before Star
>   Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace was filmed; in all previous works,
>   the concept was called "Apprentice."

Although the article is categorized as Legends, it holds in Canon, too.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I clarified that I want to know the first time it appeared in _any_ format. If it was in a story treatment for the original Star Wars, can you find a reference to that?

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED and many online references, it was 1973 in the first iteration of <sub>[*The Journal of the Whills*](https://res.cloudinary.com/jerrick/image/upload/w_720/bx5kt3oyra59inuvlcxg.jpg)</sub>

> 1973   G. Lucas *Jrnl. of Whills* (MS draft) in L
>   . Dowling *Star Wars Year by Year* (2010) 29/1   This is the story of Mace Windy..as related to us by C.J. Thorpe, padawaan learner to the famed Jedi.
>
> [Oxford English Dictionary, Padawan, n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/79309323)

Comment: I've removed a lot of the irrelevant information from the link that isn't relevant to the question. Also as per the [help page on referencing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) I have added the link to the web page and put the quote into quote markdown to indicate it is a quote. In the future please try and remember to do this also!